# vqmod background image change throws php notice in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I have installed `background_image.xml` inside vqmod xml folder to change background image in opencart. This plugins works perfectly but throwing a notice at the header.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: server in C:\wamp\www\opencart\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 54
```

this is the plugin link:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16044&filter_search=background&filter_license=0

I also tried `error_reporting(0)` but no result. Here is the code of `vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php`

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    protected function index() {
        $this->data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

        if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
            $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
        } else {
            $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
        }

        $this->data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
        $this->data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
        $this->data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();  
        $this->data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
        $this->data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
        $this->data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
        $this->data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');
        $this->data['google_analytics'] = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_google_analytics'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        // Whos Online
        if ($this->config->get('config_customer_online')) {
            $this->load->model('tool/online');

            if (isset($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                $ip = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
            } else {
                $ip = ''; 
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_HOST']) && isset($this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'])) {
                $url = 'http://' . $this->request->server['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->request->server['REQUEST_URI']; 
            } else {
                $url = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
                $referer = $this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER'];  
            } else {
                $referer = '';
            }

            $this->model_tool_online->whosonline($ip, $this->customer->getId(), $url, $referer);
        }

                if ($this->config->get('config_position')) {
            $this->data['position'] = $this->config->get('config_position');
        } else {
            $this->data['position'] = '';
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_backgroundimage') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage'))) {
            $this->data['backgroundimage'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage');
        } else {
            $this->data['backgroundimage'] = '';
        }
        $this->language->load('common/header');

        if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
            $server = HTTPS_IMAGE;
        } else {
            $server = HTTP_IMAGE;
        }   

        if ($this->config->get('config_icon') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
            $this->data['icon'] = $server . $this->config->get('config_icon');
        } else {
            $this->data['icon'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

        if ($this->config->get('config_logo') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
            $this->data['logo'] = $server . $this->config->get('config_logo');
        } else {
            $this->data['logo'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');
        $this->data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
        $this->data['text_shopping_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_shopping_cart');
        $this->data['text_search'] = $this->language->get('text_search');
        $this->data['text_welcome'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_welcome'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
        $this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
        $this->data['text_account'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
        $this->data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');

        $this->data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
        $this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');
        $this->data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
        $this->data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
        $this->data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        $this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
            $this->data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];
        } else {
            $this->data['filter_name'] = '';
        }

        // Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = array();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
                    );                      
                }

                // Level 1
                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'module/language',
'module/supermenu',
            'module/supermenu_settings',
            'module/currency',
            'module/cart'
        );

$this->data['categories'] = array();
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `$this->data['base'] = $server;` - is this the line that throws error?

Comment: `$this->data['backgroundimage'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage');` this lines throws the error this code is also under a if condition like `if ($this->config->get('config_backgroundimage') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that -  in default opencart, the below lines of code exists at the begginning of `catalog/controller/common/header.php` (line 6):

```
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }
```

In your case the above lines code got removed. Please check the file `vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php` and make necessary changes to bring back the above lines of code. If you're using more vqmod files, check them also.

An easy fix is to change (probably in your xml file):

`$this->data['backgroundimage'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage');`

to

$this->data['backgroundimage'] = $this->data['base'] . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage');

Have a nice day !

Comment: sorry to inform you that the upper code exists in both files I mean 

`vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php` and

`catalog/controller/common/header.php`

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code from the begginning of `vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php` to `if ($this->config->get('config_backgroundimage') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_backgroundimage'))` .

Comment: 2 things to note: 1.the code i mentioned doesn't exist in the code your pasted. Check carefully. 2. `$server` variable is used before it's used.